# Need help conjugating

Tags: limits, radicals

I need some help conjugating because I feel like I am overlooking a step:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 4} \frac{3(x-4)(\sqrt{x+5})}{3 - \sqrt{x+5}}$$

I've done the conjugation by multiplying by $(3 + \sqrt{x+5})$ to clear out the bottom, but how would the top look like once multiplied?

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim _{ x\rightarrow 4 } \frac { 3(x-4)(\sqrt { x+5 } ) }{ 3-\sqrt { x+5 }  } =\lim _{ x\rightarrow 4 } \frac { 3(x-4)(\sqrt { x+5 } )\left( 3+\sqrt { x+5 }  \right)  }{ \left( 3-\sqrt { x+5 }  \right) \left( 3+\sqrt { x+5 }  \right)  } =\\ =\lim _{ x\rightarrow 4 } \frac { 3(x-4)(\sqrt { x+5 } )\left( 3+\sqrt { x+5 }  \right)  }{ 4-x } =-54$$

Comment: I'm assuming you didn't plug in exactly 4 into the equation? Because that would result in having a 4 in the denominator?

Comment: because of the $4-x$ cancels in the both side of ratio so we can plug in exactly 4

Comment: Question, how did you exactly get (4-x) on the denominator? 3 - x + 5 doesn't simplify to that?

Comment: $\left( 3-\sqrt { x+5 }  \right) \left( 3+\sqrt { x+5 }  \right) ={ 3 }^{ 2 }-{ \left( \sqrt { x+5 }  \right)  }^{ 2 }=9-x-5=4-x$

Comment: Oh. my. gosh. How did I overlook that! Thank you so much!

Comment: you are welcome)